# Speed up segues and Unwind segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue, dealloc, unwind-segue

I am trying to speed up segues and unwind segues between view controllers. If I am doing anything fundamentally wrong please let me know or if I need to upload more code for context.

Here is a youtube demonstration of what is wrong: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZsAg0L-W5g&feature=youtu.be

Basically when I click 'View AR' it takes a little too long to go to the AR View Controller

Secondly when I try to unwind to the 'CollectionView Controller' it take again a little too long to unwind to the previous controller.

I also have to keep memory in mind as this is a very memory intensive application.

Any help is welcome!!!!

Here is the segue from first view controller:

```
@objc private func ViewAR(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagesOne = nil
    imagesTwo = nil
    imagesThree = nil
    imagesFour = nil
    imagesFive = nil

    //goToAR
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAR", sender: self)
}
```

As you can see above I set the images to nil for memory purposes then segue to the AR View controller

Here is the unwind segue from second view controller:

```
 @objc private func closeController(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sceneView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToSwipe", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with a custom segue (i.e., a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`), which gives you complete control over how the transition is done, and how long the transition's animation takes (or even not use animation at all).

Comment: @Rudedog thank you for your response! I'm wondering will that solve the issue or is the issue more to do with the code to be performed before segue?

Comment: The delay is almost certainly not due to the "segue" -- it's due to what you are doing setting up the new view controller. To test, add a new, plain view controller and change your `performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAR", sender: self)` to `performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTest", sender: self)` and see what happens. Most likely, it will be very quick.

Comment: @DonMag yup much quicker. So the problem is to do with what my code is doing before the segue?

Comment: @mick1996 - sounds like it. What you probably want to do is figure out the *minimum* you need to do to prepare your AR VC, and display some type of progress / activity indicator ... then, in `viewDidAppear()` you can run the actual code needed to make that VC functional.

Comment: @DonMag thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys with help from the comments, I was able to learn that the problem is not with the segue, it is with the code itself.

I have to employ the use of code like viewWillAppear

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear

Answer (score -3):

Stop using segues ,
Start using self.NavigationController.push(vc)
This is indeed best way to navigate.

Comment: Using `.push(vc)` via code is *not* better than using segues... if you looked at the video the OP linked, he's using **present**, not push... even if he ***was*** pushing onto a navigation controller stack, coding `.push` instead of using a segue would have zero effect on his issue.